# Retrieve stripe data from stripe webhook event

Tags: java, json, stripe-payments, webhooks

When implementing stripe webhook in java, I am successful in getting the event object in JSON format. The problem is I am not able to get the details like the amount, subscription_id, attributes which are in nested JSON. Getting these values from the class object is also not available. Could you please tell me how to extract these values

```
public void handle(HttpServletRequest request) {

    Stripe.apiKey = sk_test_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;

    String rawJson = "";

    try {
            rawJson = IOUtils.toString(request.getInputStream());
        } 
        catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error extracting json value : " + ex.getMessage());
         }
    Event event = APIResource.GSON.fromJson(rawJson, Event.class);
    System.out.println("Webhook event : " + event);

}
```

And I get the following response :-

```
Webhook event : <com.stripe.model.Event@1462134034 id=evt_18qdEBElSMaq70BZlEwdDJG3> JSON: {
  "id": "evt_18qdEBElSMaq70BZlEwdDJG3",
  "api_version": "2016-07-06",
  "created": 1473143919,
  "data": {
    "object": {
      "id": "in_18qcFkElSMaq70BZy1US7o3g",
      "amount_due": 4100,
      "application_fee": null,
      "attempt_count": 1,
      "attempted": true,
      "charge": "ch_18qdEBElSMaq70BZIEQvJTPe",
      "closed": true,
      "created": null,
      "currency": "usd",
      "customer": "cus_95uFN7q2HzHN7j",
      "date": 1473140172,
      "description": null,
      "discount": null,
      "ending_balance": 0,
      "forgiven": false,
      "lines": {
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "sub_95uFmJLQM3jFwP",
            "amount": 4100,
            "currency": "usd",
            "description": null,
            "discountable": true,
            "livemode": false,
            "metadata": {},
            "period": {
              "end": 1473226524,
              "start": 1473140124
            },
            "plan": {
              "id": "aug 19 01",
              "amount": 4100,
              "created": 1472448923,
              "currency": "usd",
              "interval": "day",
              "interval_count": 1,
              "livemode": false,
              "metadata": {},
              "name": "Aug 19 plan. Better than paypal",
              "statement_descriptor": null,
              "trial_period_days": null,
              "statement_description": null
            },
            "proration": false,
            "quantity": 1,
            "subscription": null,
            "type": "subscription"
          }
        ],
        "total_count": 1,
        "has_more": false,
        "request_options": null,
        "request_params": null,
        "url": "/v1/invoices/in_18qcFkElSMaq70BZy1US7o3g/lines",
        "count": null
      },
      "livemode": false,
      "metadata": {},
      "next_payment_attempt": null,
      "paid": true,
      "period_end": 1473140124,
      "period_start": 1473053724,
      "receipt_number": null,
      "starting_balance": 0,
      "statement_descriptor": null,
      "subscription": "sub_95uFmJLQM3jFwP",
      "subscription_proration_date": null,
      "subtotal": 4100,
      "tax": null,
      "tax_percent": null,
      "total": 4100,
      "webhooks_delivered_at": 1473140184
    },
    "previous_attributes": null
  },
  "livemode": false,
  "pending_webhooks": 1,
  "request": null,
  "type": "invoice.payment_succeeded",
  "user_id": null
}
```

I want to get the values like the `customer_id`, `subscription_id` , etc. But when I try to get the data using the event object, I couldn't simply do as `event.get....` . How would I extract the data.

Comment: Im not a Java dev so not familiar with this code too much but when Stripe gives you IDs you need to do another API call to get those details.

Comment: The problem is I am not able to get the invoice id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I had solved this problem. The real issue was that I was not able to retrive the `object id`, in my case the `invoiceid` (in_18qcFkElSMaq70BZy1US7o3g). This id is the id for the event occured. Meaning if it is a `payment successful` event, then the `object id` will be the `charge id` . I had to convert the `event` object to `map` then get the required attribute. Below is the complete code snippet of what I had done to solve the problem.

```
public void handle(HttpServletRequest request) {   

    Stripe.apiKey = sk_test_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;

    String rawJson = "";

    try {
         rawJson = IOUtils.toString(request.getInputStream());
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) {
       System.out.println("Error extracting json value : " + ex.getMessage());
    }

    Event event = APIResource.GSON.fromJson(rawJson, Event.class);
    System.out.println("Webhook event : " + event);

    // Converting event object to map
    ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper();
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Map<String, Object> props = m.convertValue(event.getData(), Map.class);

    // Getting required data
    Object dataMap = props.get("object");

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Map<String, String> objectMapper = m.convertValue(dataMap, Map.class);

    String invoiceId = objectMapper.get("id");

    System.out.println("invoideId : " + invoiceId);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Stripe sends [event objects](https://stripe.com/docs/api#event_object) to your webhook handler. Each event object carries another object in its [`data.object`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#event_object-data-object) attribute. The type of that object depends on the type of the event: for [`charge.*`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#event_types-charge.captured) events, it'll be a [charge object](https://stripe.com/docs/api#charge_object), for [`invoice.*`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#event_types-invoice.created) event, it'll be an [invoice object](https://stripe.com/docs/api#invoice_object), etc.

With [Stripe's Java bindings](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java#stripe-java-bindings-), you can automatically get an object of the correct type:

```
StripeObject stripeObject = event.getData().getObject();
```

`stripeObject` will be automatically cast to the correct type.

Alternatively, you can do the casting yourself:

```
if (event.getType().equals("invoice.payment_failed")) {
    Invoice invoice = event.getData().getObject();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was looking something like this from long before. Then I came up with an alternative solution which I have mentioned in this post as an answer.

Comment: `Invoice invoice = event.getData().getObject();` should be `Invoice invoice = (Invoice) event.getData().getObject();`. You still need to cast it to an `Invoice` object.