# Stripe Java API Webhook Error when casting to a Customer

Tags: java, json, stripe-payments, webhooks

I found this post: "[Retrieve stripe data from stripe webhook event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39342251/retrieve-stripe-data-from-stripe-webhook-event)" and it tells you to get the object type you have to cast from StripeObject, like
`Invoice invoice = (Invoice) event.getData().getObject();`
Class: `StripeWebhook`

```
41    Event event = ApiResource.GSON.fromJson(request.body(), Event.class);
42    if (event.getType().equals("invoice.payment_failed") || event.getType().equals("charge.failed") || event.getType().equals("charge.refunded") || event.getType().equals("customer.subscription.deleted")) {
43 ->     Customer customer = (Customer)event.getData().getObject();`
44        Plan plan = (Plan)event.getData().getObject();
45    }
```

Stacktrace:

```
[qtp2043543300-35] ERROR spark.http.matching.GeneralError -
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.stripe.model.Subscription cannot be cast to class com.stripe.model.Customer (com.stripe.model.Subscription and com.stripe.model.Customer are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
        at us.verif.bot.Stripe.StripeWebhook.lambda$startListener$0(StripeWebhook.java:43)
        at spark.RouteImpl$1.handle(RouteImpl.java:72)
        at spark.http.matching.Routes.execute(Routes.java:61)
        at spark.http.matching.MatcherFilter.doFilter(MatcherFilter.java:130)
        at spark.embeddedserver.jetty.JettyHandler.doHandle(JettyHandler.java:50)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1568)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:530)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:347)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:256)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:247)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:140)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:382)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:708)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:626)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I don't understand why it would say this because it was never a Subscription object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the contents of your `if` statement will execute if the webhook describes an invoice, charge or subscription (`customer.subscription` describes a subscription instead of a customer https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-customer.subscription.deleted)

In this case, I suspect that you're receiving a `customer.subscription.deleted` webhook but are then trying to cast the `Subscription` object to a `Customer` object.

You need to refactor your code to handle each object type separately and cast them accordingly. Alternatively you could use the `StripeObject` type, which will do your casting automatically:

`StripeObject stripeObject = event.getData().getObject();`

Comment: So if I handle them separately and tried to get the customer object it would work?

Comment: Yep, having a case for each event should sort out your problem.